# Extract Information From Date (varchar) and transmute into output

Tags: php, mysql, date, output, varchar

#### Background

I am extending a web application which must 'extract' information from a varchar variable in a mySQL table.  Now although I am quite familiar the is the most convoluted way to actually store the date in the column, I cannot change the table structure currently, or it will 'break' the rest of the system.  So with this information given, how can I output (using php) this field as so:

#### Column Data

`2013-05-12 13:18:14`

#### Output Data

```
$html .= "<td>" . $row['created_on'] . "</td>";
```

**should print:**

```
Instance1: 5/12/13
Instance2: May 12th, 2013
Instance3: 5/12/13, 1:18 PM
```

Comment: you are storing a date in a varchar type?

Comment: @Dagon yes....from a previous programmer...like i said. ass backwards

Comment: @dagon on a side note, what would be a better type, and under any forseeable circumstance...would it really `change` anything

Comment: well not to be to obvious but one of the date (DATE, DATETIME, TIMESTAMP ) ones, and why not change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:
 First turn it into its timestamp value by [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), then you can show it in many ways. Follow this link: [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$col = '2013-05-12 13:18:14';
$timestamp = strtotime($col);

$instance1 = date('m/d/y',$timestamp);
$instance2 = date('M jS Y',$timestamp);
$instance3 = date('m/d/y , h:i:s A',$timestamp);

echo $instance1.'<br>';
echo $instance2.'<br>';
echo $instance3;
```

Comment: However, what if the date was 5-3-12, so `instance2_2 would need to be .rd., not .th.`

Comment: @hawkhorrow Answer Edited. Is this what you want ?